Does the compressibility of a fluid depend on its height?
Does the compressibility of the fluid depend on any external factor, or is it an intrinsic property of the body? Like if I have a column of water, if the height of this column is nanometer or meters in size (without changing the other dimensions), the water still shows the same properties of compressibility?

Nanometers is roughly the scale of individual atoms, so the sample would almost certainly not behave as a continuous fluid like we model "water," and properties like compressibility would not have a definite meaning at that scale

Compressibility is undeniably an intrinsic property of a material, including fluids like water. It reflects the inherent ability of the material to resist volume reduction under applied pressure.
As stated. Yes, the height of fluid does not influence the inherent compressibility assuming the other dimensions to be taken constant.
External factors which influence compressibility are
Temperature: Generally, higher temperatures lead to increased compressibility,as increased thermal energy expands the intermolecular spacing, making the fluid less resistant to compression.
Intermolecular Forces: Stronger intermolecular forces between the fluid molecules make the material less compressible. For instance, water exhibits greater compressibility than oil due to weaker hydrogen bonding in water compared to the stronger van der Waals forces in oil.
Material Structure: Densely packed structures, like those in solids, tend to be less compressible compared to loosely arranged structures in gases. This is because there's less space for further packing in a dense structure under pressure.

Just to be sure, so the same can be extended about the incompressible ones?

@GabrielMarino I've started properties of general fluids. And regarding incomprehensible fluids(ideal condition) these properties will tend to be irrational. As every fluid has some tendency to contract under applied pressure.ㅤAnd the same cannot be extended about incomprehensible fluids.

I see thank you, just to finish the topic, do you have any literature on the topic you could recommend me?

@GabrielMarino For what purpose and specify.

I trying to solve the convection-diffusion equation of a laminar portion of water enclosed in a microscopic space and my background in fluids is very weak. So anything is good for me, I'm a bachelor in Physics, but my undergrad course don't have any specific about fluids, just a basic introduction in a general course of basic physics.

@GabrielMarino if you wish to study introduction to fluids mechanics you can study it from Resnick haliday, but as you are a physics graduate and iff want to study molecular hydrodynamics try - [Molecular hydrodynamics by J.P. Boon] and [Transport phenomena by R.B. Bird, W.E. Stewart]
